# Get the max value for each column in a table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table for player stats like so:

```
player_id | game_id | rec | rec_yds | td | pas_att | pas_yds | ...
--------------------------------------------------------
1         |    3    |  1  |    5    |  0 |    3    |   20    |
2         |    3    |  0  |    8    |  1 |    7    |   20    |
3         |    3    |  3  |    9    |  0 |    0    |   0     |
4         |    3    |  5  |   15    |  0 |    0    |   0     |
```

I want to return the max values for every column in the table except player_id and game_id.

I know I can return the max of one single column by doing something like so:

`SELECT MAX(rec) FROM stats`

However, this table has almost 30 columns, so I would just be repeating the query below, for all 30 stats, just replacing the name of the stat.
`SELECT MAX(rec) as rec FROM stats`

This would get tedious real quick, and wont scale.

Is there any way  to kind of loop over columns, get every column in the table and return the max value like so:

```
player_id | game_id | rec | rec_yds | td | pas_att | pas_yds | ...
--------------------------------------------------------
4         |    3    |  5  |    15   |  1 |    7    |   20    |
```

Comment: are you limited to implement this inside the database? it seems easily doable on the application level with a query builder, you can get the column names and types, build the query @Bergi suggested then run it

Comment: Hmm, I would have expected writing this question to take longer than writing `max(..)` for 30 columns with a decent SQL editor that offers code completion. If you need that frequently, put it into a view.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum of multiple columns in a single query:

```
SELECT
  MAX(rec) AS rec_max,
  MAX(rec_yds) AS rec_yds_max,
  MAX(td) AS td_max,
  MAX(pas_att) AS pas_att_max,
  MAX(pas_yds) AS pas_yds_max
FROM stats
```

However, there is no way to dynamically get an arbitrary number of columns. You could dynamically build the query by loading all column names of the table, then apply conditions such as "*except player_id and game_id*", but that cannot be done within the query itself.